# How to set span fixed width for span in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am working in a e-commerce website ,In this I need to fix the following issue.
when I add product to the cart count is added but the span grow it's size based on count how can I fix this issue...

[image]

When I add 100 products this is the span width.

[image]

When I reduce the product count Span width also reduced

[image]

If I remove the product Span get's it's normal width

What I need is I want the span width as it's normal width ,when I add products to the cart the counter span only grows it's width.

This is the code I written...

```
<form class="form-inline">
          <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-prepend ">
              <span class="input-group-text" id="crt">
                  <span class=" notification-counter badge badge-danger">{{nCount}}</span>
                <i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-flip-horizontal text-primary" style="font-size:30px"></i>   
              </span>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control bg-white" value="My Cart ({{nCount}})" readonly>
          </div>
        </form>
```

CSS

```
.notification-counter {   
    position: relative;
    bottom: 12px;
    background-color: rgba(212, 19, 13, 1);
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    font: 11px Verdana;
}
```

and how to make the counter span shape as round ,when I add a single product it's look like this

[image]
Thanks ...

Comment: specify a fixed height/width and center content

Comment: I think there are many problems in HTML/CSS. Everything under input-group-text is span (inline elements) which grows size. You either need to change display value for fa-cart and input-group-text to "inline-block" or change them to div with "display:inline-block", same effect. You use font-awesome for icons, I don't know how they behave being a div elements. I have a snippet but it is not final solution, but just a rough idea (change cart items value to see the effect)
https://jsfiddle.net/qyhqag3j/14/

Comment: It's worked for me,Thanks

Comment: Can you help me in this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938614/bootstrap-slider-shows-the-active-item-two-times-in-angular4